# simultaneously begin operations on several execution threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

i came across an interview question which required me to simulate a car race .

this was no problem in general , all i did is call the car.Race() method which i built 
which loops until it the car reaches its destination ( this is not important !)

what was tricky is to make all 10 threads which the car "raced" on (thread per car )call Car.Race()
simultaneously and not one after the other

```
  Action<Car,ManualResetEvent> raceDel = (car,handel) =>{
        handel.WaitOne();
        car.Race();
  }

  main()
  {
     ManualResetEvent [] handels = new ManualResetEvent[num_cars];
     Car [] cars = new Car[num_cars];
     for(int i = 0 ; i < num_cars ; i++)
     {
        handels[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        cars[i] = new Car();
        raceDel.BeginInvoke(cars[i],handels[i],null,null);
     } 
      // the question lies here  , i'm looking for something along the lines of 
        WaitHandel.SetAll(handels); // which no such method exists :)

  }
```

thread one could start and the car would reach the end of the course before thread 5 even started its execution .

what i did was send a manualresetevent into each thread and called waitOne() on it 
the problem now was with what element in the framework could i signal an entire array of ManualResetEvent simultaneously  .

WaitHandle has a method  WaitHandle.WaitAll(MRE_Array) which would wait for an array of MRE
to call send , i'm looking for something like the opposite which would invoke Set() on an entire array of manualresetevent .

any ideas ?

any work arounds  or other synchronization objects that might do the trick would also be well received 
thanks in advance 
eran.

Comment: Missing information: exact question and code snippet you provided.

Comment: i don't think watching me call BeginInvoke on a delegate which calls some arbitrary method the point of the question. 
but ill provide you with the main scope of it , if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need one `ManualResetEvent`.

Pass it to all your threads and they can all wait on the same event.

When the Wait Handle is signalled, all blocked threads are allowed to continue.

This does not mean they will all continue execution concurrently - that's up to the OS scheduler - but in practice it will be close, given enough physical cores.